Issue with Redlock Stuck in Redis Cluster Setup
Environment:
Redlock Version: 3.1.2 (also tested with 5.0.0-beta.2)
Redis Version: 7.0.4
ioredis Version: 5.3.2
Redis Setup: Cluster with 6 nodes, created using Docker Compose
Issue Details:
When using a Redis cluster setup, the Redlock implementation gets stuck during the lock acquisition process. This issue does not occur when using a single standalone Redis node.
Code Snippet for Redis Provider:
export const redisProvider: Provider = {
  provide: 'REDIS_CLIENT',
  useFactory: (configService: ConfigService): Redis | Cluster => {
    const clusterNodes = configService.get<string[]>('redis.clusterNodes');

    if (clusterNodes && clusterNodes.length > 0) {
      const nodes = clusterNodes.map((uri) => {
        const url = new URL(uri);
        return {
          host: url.hostname,
          port: parseInt(url.port, 10),
        };
      });

      const clusters = new Redis.Cluster(nodes, {
        clusterRetryStrategy: (times) => Math.min(times * 100, 2000),
        slotsRefreshTimeout: 2000,
        dnsLookup: (address, callback) => callback(null, address),
        redisOptions: {
          keyPrefix: configService.get<string>('redis.prefix'),
        },
      });

      return clusters;
    } else {
      const redis = new Redis(configService.get<string>('redis.host'), {
        keyPrefix: configService.get<string>('redis.prefix'),
      });

      return redis;
    }
  },
  inject: [ConfigService],
};

Docker Compose file:
version: '3'
services:
  redis-1:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server', '/etc/redis/redis.conf']
    volumes:
      - ./node-1/data:/data
      - ./node-1/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - 6371:6379
      - 16371:16379
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.11
  redis-2:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server', '/etc/redis/redis.conf']
    volumes:
      - ./node-2/data:/data
      - ./node-2/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - '6372:6379'
      - 16372:16379
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.12
  redis-3:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server', '/etc/redis/redis.conf']
    volumes:
      - ./node-3/data:/data
      - ./node-3/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - '6373:6379'
      - 16373:16379
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.13
  redis-4:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server', '/etc/redis/redis.conf']
    volumes:
      - ./node-4/data:/data
      - ./node-4/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - '6374:6379'
      - 16374:16379
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.14
  redis-5:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server', '/etc/redis/redis.conf']
    volumes:
      - ./node-5/data:/data
      - ./node-5/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - '6375:6379'
      - 16375:16379
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.15
  redis-6:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server', '/etc/redis/redis.conf']
    volumes:
      - ./node-6/data:/data
      - ./node-6/conf/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
    ports:
      - '6376:6379'
      - 16376:16379
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.16
  independent-redis-1:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server']
    ports:
      - '6381:6379'
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.17
  independent-redis-2:
    image: redis:7.0.4
    command: ['redis-server']
    ports:
      - '6382:6379'
    networks:
      redis_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.38.0.18
networks:
  redis_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.38.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.38.0.1


Questions:
Compatibility: Can Redlock work seamlessly with Redis clusters, or is it intended to be used only with independent Redis nodes?
Configuration Issue: If Redlock does support Redis clusters, where might my configuration be incorrect or suboptimal?
I am experiencing an issue where Redlock appears to get stuck when trying to acquire a lock in a Redis cluster environment. This problem does not occur when using a single independent Redis node.
Steps to Reproduce:
Set up a Redis cluster with 6 nodes using Docker Compose.
Implement Redlock with the provided configuration.
Attempt to acquire a lock using the executeWithLock method.
Observations:
The lock acquisition process gets stuck in a cluster setup.
Works fine with a standalone Redis node.
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
